# Run cucumber features with Netbeans on Mac Os

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, cucumber, bdd

I was using BDD in a project with Netbeans and it was running fine on a Linux. But when I changed to a MacBook, the features are not executing anymore, giving this error:

> Cannot run "cucumber", error=2, No such file or directory.

But if using Command-line, I go into the folder that has the features and run it, it works fine. So I think that the problem should be some NetBeans configurations or OS X configurations. I have tried a lot of different cucumber plugins, but the error is the same, nothing changes.

Does anyone have this problem or knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a plugin? If yes, which one? In general, cucumber is not supported in NetBeans by default.